# Sed replacement in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, glob

I´m wondering how can i just replace this variable easily in BASH:

```
VARIABLE1="VALUE2=somestring2 VALUE3=TRUE"
```

I need just to change **VALUE2=somestring2** (which is just part of the string) with a new value that replaces it:

i am just using this:

```
VARIABLE1="${VARIABLE1//VALUE2=[a-z0-9-]*/}VALUE2=${VALUE2}"
```

where **VALUE2=${VALUE2}** is a new value that i specify in some line.

but there are two problems here:

1- the line where i overwrite the **VALUE2=somestring2** deletes **VALUE3=TRUE** from **VARIABLE1**

2- looks like after overwrite **VALUE2**, it puts a "space" at the beginning of "VALUE2=somestring2"

echo $VARIABLE1
" VALUE2=somestring2"

Any way to fix this?

Comment: It is not a regex that you are using, it is a glob. That is why `*` grabs all text to the end. And you are not using sed here.

Comment: thanks for that. I see that * is messing what i want to do. But i did not find any way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
shopt -s extglob
VARIABLE1=${VARIABLE1/VALUE2=*([a-z0-9-])/VALUE2=$VALUE2}
```

- `shopt -s extglob` turns on extended globbing in Bash.  That enables (among other things) the built-in substitution mechanism to use a form of regular expressions (`*([a-z0-9-])` here).  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)
- Note that ALL_UPPERCASE variable names like `VARIABLE1` are potentially dangerous.  They can clash with the many special ALL_UPPERCASE variables that exist.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).  Names like `variable1` are generally safe.